# How to run validation on a slice of a redux-form FieldArray state

Tags: redux-form

I am running something very similar to the example here:

http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/examples/fieldArrays/

Say I want to add a list of members and a list of hobbies under each member, like in the example above.

What is different from the example above is,  I want to also be able to validate each member, before I am able to add additional members or hobbies for that member.

Similarly, I also want to be able to validate each hobby, before I can add another hobby.

In other words, I want to be able to treat each entry in the `FieldArray` as a form and each add button as a submit function for that form.

I would have a `validateMember` and `validateHobby` validation functions that I would run against the respective `FieldArray` entries.

I am not aware of any feature of redux-form that allows running synchronous validation on a subset of the form's state. Alternatively, I also cannot treat everything as a form as then I would lose all the nesting (i.e. which hobby belongs to each address).

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think if you can trigger the validation when pressing 'Add hobby', you could validate any fields you like. You would have to pass some flag to validate call to identify that I think. 
I am currently looking for a way to trigger validation in a similar way. I think I'm going to post a question for it as well.

Comment: Can't you just add field level validation to your hobby fields and disable the "Add Hobby" button if form is invalid?